# how add a hyperlink in pdf page to page using itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, pdf, c#-4.0, hyperlink, navigateurl

I want to add or create a hyperlink in bottom of the PDF page and it will redirecting to another page by using **itextsharp**. and next thing is for example if i have 50 pages PDF file. add 3 pages to it. and in 50th page i want 2 hyperlinks at bottom of the page. one to go for 51st page and another one to for 52nd page. next thing is if i am click back button  in 51st page and 52nd page also it will come to 50th page.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Using PdfAnnotation to create link

```
PdfAnnotation annotation;
                annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateLink(
                stamper.Writer, rect, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,
                new PdfAction(string.Format(IMDB, screening.movie.Imdb))
              );
              stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, page);
```

More details to refer this link

http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter07&ex=TimetableAnnotations2